# Dispute Off-Topic

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

How can I dispute one of my questions having had been marked as off-topic?

I have asked [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/759264/ping-resolving-to-strange-address) on Server Fault after I discovered that I [should put the question on Server Fault](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165507/on-which-stack-exchange-site-should-i-ask-question-about-dns).

Comment: "Why is my consumer device doing something odd I don't understand?" doesn't read like a sys-admin type question.

Comment: Oh, but it's not a "consumer device". It's admittedly a home server. But, this server is performing tasks which are related to sysadmin tasks. The question is a NetBIOS and DNS question which is at the sysadmin level.

Comment: To be a question for SF it would need to be asked from the sysadmin that manage the gear, as for any advanced advice it will impossible to test without changing some configuration, and maybe it's already a know problem that your helpdesk can answer you.

Comment: At the request of the OP the question has now been moved to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/1044993/ping-resolving-to-strange-address)

Comment: The question you posted here bears very little resemblance to the inquiry you made on meta.

Comment: @JennyD, I'm not sure that I understand. This question is the inquiry that I made on meta. As such, it should be exactly the same as the inquiry that I made on meta.

Comment: You gave a link to a question on Meta.SE where you asked about where you should post a question on DNS and redirection of a subdomain. You were pointed towards Serverfault. But the question you posted on Serverfault, according to your own link above, was about client settings for host name resolution - not the same thing at all. So claiming that you were told to ask that question here is misleading, since the question you actually posted was entirely different from the one you asked about.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating @JennyD. You're exactly right. If I had read the meta answer thoroughly I would have realized that questions regarding domain name resolution performed by a client does not belong in Server Fault. Server Fault would allow questions regarding the configuration or behavior of a domain name server; these questions are not in the same vein as my question. My question has since been moved to the SU site where I think it'll enjoy more comfortable accommodations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I dispute one of my questions having had been marked as off-topic?

The [help pages](https://serverfault.com/help/reopen-questions) offer a number of approaches (emphasis mine):

> ... If you see a question and you disagree with the stated reason of its closure, you should **first try to edit the question to improve it** as much as possible. **Read the close notice and any comments carefully** to address concerns raised there. Closed questions that receive edits within the first 5 days of closure are automatically put into a review queue to be considered for reopening.
>
> Additionally, you can:
>
> 1. **Leave a comment on the question itself** calling for it to be reopened. Be detailed: explain why the question shouldn't have been closed. Be constructive: name-calling is as likely to drive folks away as it is win them to your cause. Remember, anyone on the site with at least 3,000 reputation points can vote to reopen a question - even if a moderator closed it.
> 2. Be sure that you've **read the close notice** and any comments on the question so you can **address any concerns** raised there. Addressing the concerns often means editing the post, which any user may do.
> 3. **Flag the question** for moderator attention. Again, explain why it should be reopened. There is more than one moderator, and moderators do reconsider their decisions.

Asking for clarification on Meta typically also attracts the attention from our active community members and moderators and I have since moved your question to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1044993/ping-resolving-to-strange-address), as you requested in a comment.

Answer (score 8):

We routinely close home user questions. The text of the close reason is quite clear (my emphasis)

> "Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. **Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User**, and questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow." –

Comment: You're right, questions should be moved. How do I request that my question be moved to another [SE site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/moving-my-own-question-to-another-stack-exchange-site)?

Comment: @fuzzybear3965 : you flag your always friendly `*cough*` moderator and they may (or may not) decide that your migration request has merit.Consider it done.

Comment: Thanks! I see that it's been moved to SU.

Answer (score 7):

This quote is taken directly from the page meta.SE page [you linked to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165508/136475):

> Server Fault is for Information Technology Professionals needing
>   expert answers related to managing computer systems in a professional
>   capacity.

So it appears you read *some* of that answer, but not all of it.

Now, your question is not a bad question. It's just off-topic for Server Fault. As is the case with **any** SE site, the burden is on the user to read each site's Help section to learn what topics and environments are appropriate for the site.